# drupal edit attachment field of a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

I have a content type named Properties, users can create the content types 
I have file cck field in the content type (properties), now I want to add the attachments to the or edit the attachments field only in a block or panel for the particular property.

Not showing all the fields when user try to edit the content type.

I have heard that this is possible in panels using contexts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want here, but it sounds like you want to change the visibility/editability of fields based on role and display.

To change the visibility and/or editibility based on role, use something like this
http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

To change it based on display, use the "display fields" tab on the content type edit form.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://drupal.org/project/editablefields